# angularjs ng-click can't change $scope variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm baffled here I've got a controller which looks like this..

```
angular.module('publicRegApp')
  .controller('CompanyNameController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Title One';

    $scope.onSearch = function(){
        console.log("clicked");
        $scope.title = "Title Two";
    }

  });
```

in my template I have:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="onSearch()">Search</button>
```

When I click the button the console log gets fired but the $scope.title doesn't change. I'm so confused please help :-(

Comment: where is the title injected in your view? how do you conclude it does not change?

Comment: Check your title by wrapping it like <div ng-controller="CompanyNameController">{{title}}</div>

Comment: The {{title}} is contained within a view, I am assigning View and Controller via the modules config $routeProvider - {{title}} gets set fine when I load up the page but just won't change when I click?

Comment: @user1803975 , Did you check my answer?

Comment: change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: learn the basics...... first

Comment: Thanks CodeHater - that's fixed the problem :-)

Comment: type="submit" wont be an issue here

Comment: And thanks Vicky for your constructive comment criticism

Answer (score 3):

It works if you take care of these things:

1. Make sure you have `ng-app="publicRegApp"` somewhere
2. Correct you Javascript from `angular.module("publicRegApp")` to
   `angular.module("publicRegApp", [])` which indicate that you don't
   depended on other angular module.
3. Make sure `{{title}}` is in the controller scope

Here is working example: http://jsbin.com/xotaf/5/edit

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your {{title}} in template is outside of scope for controller. I would strongly recommend to check it ;)

$scope.$apply is very bad suggestion, it's not doing what you think it's doing

------------EDIT---------

check this plunker pls

http://plnkr.co/edit/0LyUaGWK4J5c9EY74ndw?p=preview

Comment: `My guess is that your {{title}} in template is outside of scope for controller. I would strongly recommend to check it` Then how  to first time it working?

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, I'm not sure how {{title}} could be out of scope as it gets set to 'Title One'. The problem is it won't update to 'Title Two'?

Comment: @user1803975 Have you tried this <div ng-controller="CompanyNameController">{{title}}</div>

Comment: I've edited post with plunker, it seems to work, please check it out

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure why but having

```
<button type="submit">
```

was the issue. Changing to

```
<button type="button">
```

fixed it.

I then realised I should probably be using ng-submit on the buttons's parent  element which also fixed the problem (as long as I leave the button as submit of course)

Comment: eaither you choose
   `<input type="button">`
or
    `<button></button>`